# Unable to load DLL 'libargon2.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dll, build, dllimport

Geting below error while calling service

Message authentication failed.
 Service: https://dashboard-dev.onsolve.com/DashboardSTS/Service.svc/IWSTrust13/
 Action: http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue
 ClientIdentity: 
 ActivityId: 
 SecurityTokenException: Unknown internal error. ---> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libargon2.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

If I manually add it in bin folder,tried both x86/64  .I am getting below error
Message authentication failed.
 Service: https://dashboard-dev.onsolve.com/DashboardSTS/Service.svc/IWSTrust13/
 Action: http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue
 ClientIdentity: 
 ActivityId: 
 SecurityTokenException: Unknown internal error. ---> BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the client credential that the Message security mode requires? How do you invoke the service? generally speaking, the invocation by using a client proxy does not include the library like `libargon2.dll`. why do you have to refer to this library on the client-side? The error seemingly indicates that the DLL is key to the issue. Is this class library an encapsulation of WCF service calls?
Look forward to your reply.

Comment: Liphsoft is net wrapper for libargon2. I am consuming Liphsoft, internally it uses libargon2 unmanaged code.

Comment: You could attempt to consume the service in a separate console application to exclude the issue in the current project.